# svn -- how to save password, but not in plaintext?

Tags: linux, svn

I am using svn 1.8 on fluxbox.  It appears I have to set  `store-plaintext-passwords = yes` in order to make the password saving works. But I don't want to save my password in plain text.

Comment: depending on your desktop environment, subversion can support other password stores [`gnome-keyring / kwallet`](http://www.timelordz.com/wiki/Subversion_Password_Management).

Comment: @Petesh this kind of baffles me --why is it dependent on desktop environment? I am on fluxbox, which I guess doesn't work?

Comment: you should be able to get the gnome keyring to work on fluxbox - google is your friend in this respect. Once you have a secure keyring working, then you can configure subversion to work with it.

Comment: for whatever reason, keyring-stores are often bundled with desktop environments (and share a number of libraries). but usually you *can* use any keyring-store with a different DE as well (though you might need to search for one that doesn't pull in GBytes of dependencies...)

Answer (score 4):

In `~/.subversion/config` file just add the valid password stores. For example my config:

```
### Section for authentication and authorization customizations.
[auth]
### Set password stores used by Subversion. They should be
### delimited by spaces or commas. The order of values determines
### the order in which password stores are used.
### Valid password stores:
### gnome-keyring (Unix-like systems)
### kwallet (Unix-like systems)
### gpg-agent (Unix-like systems)
### keychain (Mac OS X)
### windows-cryptoapi (Windows)
password-stores = gpg-agent,gnome-keyring,kwallet
### To disable all password stores, use an empty list:
password-stores = yes
```